# How to find key trees/features from a trained random forest?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using Scikit-Learn Random Forest Classifier and trying to extract the meaningful trees/features in order to better understand the prediction results.

I found this method which seems relevant in the documention (http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.get_params), but couldn't find an example how to use it.

I am also hoping to visualize those trees if possible, any relevant code would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the relative feature importances, read the [relevant section of the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance-evaluation) along with the code of the linked examples in that same section.

The trees themselves are stored in the `estimators_` attribute of the random forest instance (only after the call to the `fit` method). Now to extract a "key tree" one would first require you to define what it is and what you are expecting to do with it.

You could rank the individual trees by computing there score on held out test set but I don't know what expect to get out of that.

Do you want to prune the forest to make it faster to predict by reducing the number of trees without decreasing the aggregate forest accuracy?

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! My goal is to find which features are more influential both because I am trying to engineer new features, and would like to see how they are performing, and also so I could optimize the forest for speed and size as you mentioned. Since a combination of features might behave differently than their individual importance, I thought about searching for the best performing trees (the metric would be a function of their prediction error). I assumed this is calculated as part of the fitting process, for the tree weights in each prediction?

Comment: In random forests, there is no tree weighting. All trees are equal. This is a major difference with boosted trees.

Comment: Right, sorry for that. I am trying to understand how the importance is calculate, would the code in "_tree.pyx" under "compute_feature_importances()" be the right one? If so what are n_samples, init_error and best_error please?

Comment: This is it but myself I am not familiar with it so I cannot answer off the tip of my head.

Answer (score 16):

I think you're looking for Forest.feature_importances_.  This allows you to see what the relative importance of each input feature is to your final model.  Here's a simple example.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 


#Lets set up a training dataset.  We'll make 100 entries, each with 19 features and
#each row classified as either 0 and 1.  We'll control the first 3 features to artificially
#set the first 3 features of rows classified as "1" to a set value, so that we know these are the "important" features.  If we do it right, the model should point out these three as important.  
#The rest of the features will just be noise.
train_data = [] ##must be all floats.
for x in range(100):
    line = []
    if random.random()>0.5:
        line.append(1.0)
        #Let's add 3 features that we know indicate a row classified as "1".
        line.append(.77)
        line.append(.33)
        line.append(.55)
        for x in range(16):#fill in the rest with noise
            line.append(random.random())
    else:
        #this is a "0" row, so fill it with noise.
        line.append(0.0)
        for x in range(19):
            line.append(random.random())        
    train_data.append(line)
train_data = np.array(train_data)


# Create the random forest object which will include all the parameters
# for the fit.  Make sure to set compute_importances=True
Forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, compute_importances=True)

# Fit the training data to the training output and create the decision
# trees.  This tells the model that the first column in our data is the classification,
# and the rest of the columns are the features.
Forest = Forest.fit(train_data[0::,1::],train_data[0::,0])

#now you can see the importance of each feature in Forest.feature_importances_
# these values will all add up to one.  Let's call the "important" ones the ones that are above average.
important_features = []
for x,i in enumerate(Forest.feature_importances_):
    if i>np.average(Forest.feature_importances_):
        important_features.append(str(x))
print 'Most important features:',', '.join(important_features)
#we see that the model correctly detected that the first three features are the most important, just as we expected!
```

Comment: It seems that the `compute_importances` is no longer supported.

Comment: 'feature_importances_' appears to be the new attribute for the sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier v0.17.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I visualize the tree:

First make the model after you have done all of the preprocessing, splitting, etc:

```
# max number of trees = 100
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Make predictions:

```
# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Then make the plot of importances.  The variable `dataset` is the name of the original dataframe.

```
# get importances from RF
importances = classifier.feature_importances_

# then sort them descending
indices = np.argsort(importances)

# get the features from the original data set
features = dataset.columns[0:26]

# plot them with a horizontal bar chart
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.barh(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], color='b', align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), features[indices])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
```

This yields a plot as below:

[image]